# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types

Tags: sql, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to get all activity for tasks and I am using a DTO layer using automapper but it's crashing when i call getAll endpoint in automapping objects.
I am using repo-service models and MVC code first approach.
I am not seeing the issue or from where it's coming.
note: it's working with insert but not with getall
so i don't think the mapping is the issue here but still it crash with automapper error.

**error**

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

**start up**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Auto Mapper Configurations
            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new ProjectProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new SprintProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new TaskProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new UserProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new UserSprintProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new UserProjectProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new GroupProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new SprintSchemaProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new SprintTypeProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new GroupTypeProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new CommentProfile());
                mc.AddProfile(new ActivityProfile());
            });
            IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper)
    }
```

**Activity model class**

```
        [Table("activity")]
    public class Activity
    {
           
            [Key]
            [Column("activity_id")]
            public int ActivityId { get; set; }
            [Column("activity_info")]
            [StringLength(225)]
            public string ActivityInfo { get; set; }

            [Column("activity_created_date")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public DateTime ActivityCreatedDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(TaskId))]
        [Column("task_id")]
        public int? TaskId { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Activities")]
        public virtual Task Task{ get; set; }
}
```

**Activity DTO class**

```
 public class ActivityDto {         
    public int activityId { get; set; }
    public string activityInfo { get; set; }

    public DateTime activityCreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? taskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Task task { get; set; }

}
```

**Activity Profile**

```
   public class ActivityProfile :Profile
    {
        public ActivityProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ActivityDto, Activity>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ActivityId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.activityId))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ActivityInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.activityInfo))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ActivityCreatedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.activityCreatedDate))
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.Task, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.task))
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.TaskId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.taskId))
                      .ReverseMap();
}
}
```

**activity controller**

```
       private readonly IMapper _mapper;
            private readonly IActivityService _activityService;

            public TaskActivityController(IActivityService activityService, IMapper mapper)
            {
                _mapper = mapper;
                _activityService = activityService;
            }
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetAllActivities")]
            public ActionResult<ActivityDto> GetAll()
            {
                var data = _activityService.GetAll();
                List<ActivityDto> dataDTO = _mapper.Map<List<ActivityDto>>(data);
                return Json(dataDTO);
            }
```

Comment: What is the rest of innerException message?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad this is the whole message without any further information